# Steam API, XML Retrieval into PHP $Variable

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to retrieve Match Information from the Steam API and as my PHP & XML knowledge is limited, I'e been using your fantastic website to help me achieve this task thus far, but have become stuck. After about 6 hours of trying to find a solution I thought i'd ask the question here, as there is likely a really simple solution to this.

The direct URL to pull this information from the Steam API is as follows:
https:// api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=123456789&format=xml&key=mysteamkey

I've created a html form to submit the MatchID to this, so that I can change this as required, the code for this is as follows:

```
<form action="retrieval.php" method="post">
MatchID <input type="text" name="MatchID">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the retrieval.php:

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('https' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url1 = 'https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=';
$url2 = $_POST["MatchID"];
$url3 = '&format=xml&key=<mykeyhere>';
$urlfinal = $url1 . $url2 . $url3;

$xml = file_get_contents($urlfinal, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

If I print_r($xml); this using an example MatchID, I get the following:
http://www.nimserv.com/chromebrowser.png
http://www.nimserv.com/pagesource.png
so in my naive understanding it seems to be retrieving the data successfully.

So finally getting to the point, apologies if this is long winded. How would I follow on from this to be able to have each line in a format which could be queried against, in preparation to insert into a database? I've tried using some XMLParse methods and have been able to convert this into html text and I could likely write a script to then take this information and sort it appropriately, however I'm sure there is a much better way of doing this, than that one. As mentioned my programming knowledge is limited, so I'm learning a lot as I work through this.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate any assistance offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested:

```
foreach( $xml->players->player as $player ) {
  echo 'id: ', $player->account_id, "\n";
  ...
}
```